# How to add an image to the right side of an input form and make it work as a search button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to edit one of the nav bars from bootstrap website and would like to make a costume input form with a button with an external image , i've tried messing with css but the code i was taking notes from was different from this one and it didn't work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
   <div>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Post layout</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Pages</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shortcodes</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="search-bar">
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><img src="\searchicon.png"></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              </div>
         </nav>   
   </div>
    <!-- /NAVBAR -->
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.parent{
position: realtive;
}
.image {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
}
.input-box {
height : 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
<input class="input-box">
<button class="image"><img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:15px"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```